# Sound amplifier's pspice simulation result is wrong

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, pspice

I found a circuit of a simple amplifier on the Internet and simulated it with pspice.

[image]

[image]

I ran a simulation by entering the above circuit and all values, but the result did not come out.

[image]

If the value of the resistance corresponding to the earphone is greatly increased to 1G ohm, it is confirmed that the value is amplified, but this value seems to be affected by the DC power supply, not by the transistor. In addition to this circuit, I searched for numerous amplifier circuits on the Internet and ran simulations through pspice, but I kept getting similar results. Is there something wrong with the program?

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your simulator.

Comment: Are you sure your transistor aren't saturated or off? Not every single circuit on the internet is good or works

Comment: R4 is not 3.3kΩ, it's 3.3Ω

Comment: And the earpiece resistance... My guess is much higher than 8 ohms.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

- Q1 and Q2 part number could be wrong: **Q**2N3904 may not be a valid part, please verify.
- R4 is 3.3 Ohms, not 3.3k.

Comment: Good spot on the 3R3.